# How to save a byte array to a file in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to download files from the server.I have VBA code which makes a call to a C# web service and gets an array of bytes..I am now trying to figure out,how can I write the byte array to a file on my local machine through VBA code

Comment: You are using C# and why do you want to use VBA to the latter part? Why not do all in C#? Can you describe a bit more what you are really trying to do here? :)

Comment: @bonCodigo - I suspect the user1984867 does not have a choice: most likely the client app is an Excel spreadsheet that pulls down data and displays it. Often developers don't have a choice over the technologies they use - that choice is made by the business or is made for them by other constraints.

Answer (score 9):

```
open "output.bin" for binary access write as #1
lWritePos=1
put #1, lWritePos, vData
close #1
```

http://www.visualbasic.happycodings.com/Files_Directories_Drives/code52.html

Comment: See my answer (which should have been a comment to this post) below

Answer (score 3):

vData needs to be defined as `Dim vData() as byte`. The decodeBase64 function which converts the (image) encoded string (link to it in this answer) returns a byte array and if it is passed back to a variant, the resulting data file will not open.

Comment: It would have helped to explain **why** there is such a need. Right now, we can only guess, or perhaps have [educated guesses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13940267/656988).