# Serializing and deserializing a file in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, serialization, deserialization

I feel dirty asking this because it's such a hacky workaround, but I have a project where the deliverable must be a single .xlsm file. However, we have no restrictions on what files that deliverable may write or execute. VBA and Excel's macro editor have limitations that don't work with the project.

So I'm trying to save the binary values of a Python interpreter in a worksheet and then write that .exe to the client's computer when the macro is run. (It's pretty much a virus and a bad idea, I know, but the requirements are strict and unchangeable.)

I have a macro to read python.exe into a worksheet:

```
Function ReadFromFile(path)

    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Dim fileInt As Integer: fileInt = FreeFile
    Open path For Binary Access Read As #fileInt
    ReDim bytes(0 To LOF(fileInt) - 1)
    Get #fileInt, , bytes
    Close #fileInt

    Set ReadFromFile = bytes

End Function


Sub ReadCompiler_Click()

    Dim path As String: path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\python.exe.original"
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    bytes = ReadFromFile(path)

    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Worksheets("PythonEXE").Range("A1")

    For Each chunk In bytes
        cell.Value = chunk
        Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next chunk

End Sub
```

I have verified that this copies the binary file byte-for-byte into column A of my `PythonEXE` worksheet.

My problem is when writing the bytes back to a file, the written file is significantly different than the original. I'm using the following functions to write from the worksheet to the output file:

```
Function WriteToFile(path, data)

    Dim fileNo As Integer
    fileNo = FreeFile

    Open path For Binary Access Write As #fileNo

    Put #fileNo, 1, data    

    Close #fileNo

End Function

Sub WriteCompiler_Click()

    Dim TotalRows As Long
    Dim bytes() As Byte

    TotalRows = Worksheets("PythonEXE").Rows(Worksheets("PythonEXE").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim bytes(TotalRows)

    For i = 1 To TotalRows
        bytes(i) = CByte(Worksheets("PythonEXE").Cells(i, 1).Value)
    Next i

    Dim path As String: path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\python.exe.written"
    WriteToFile path, bytes

End Sub
```

Why is my output binary different than the input binary? It's not human readable, but their checksums are different and when I open them both in an IDE the output file looks like it has a bunch of rectangle glyphs at the beginning where the input file does not.

Comment: You can embed arbitrary xml in a .xlsx file via "Custom XML Parts".  Would that help

Comment: [This might be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658840/write-hex-string-to-file-in-binary-mode/54660806#54660806)

Comment: That is a good way to do it, but I've already got it working with the bytes of the file stored as 0-255 integers in a column of a hidden spreadsheet. I might change it to use XML though- there are 97,000 bytes so it's a bit slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a couple of things (guided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24310004/539997) to get around the problem:

1. When VBA writes a `Variant`, it puts some header info in the output. So I changed `WriteToFile` to copy `data` to a `Byte` array before writing it:

```
Dim buffer() As Byte
ReDim buffer(UBound(data))
buffer = data
For i = 0 To UBound(data)
        Put #fileNo, i + 1, CByte(buffer(i))
Next i
```

2. I had an off-by-one error by going to UBound(data) instead of UBound(data) - 1. This is a little hairy because `Put` takes the write position as one-based instead of zero-based, but array indexers are zero-based:

```
Dim buffer() As Byte
ReDim buffer(UBound(data))
buffer = data
For i = 0 To (UBound(data) - 1)
        Put #fileNo, i + 1, CByte(buffer(i))
Next i
```

Here's the full solution:

```
Function WriteToFile(path, data)

    Dim fileNo As Integer
    fileNo = FreeFile

    Open path For Binary Access Write As #fileNo

    Dim buffer() As Byte
    ReDim buffer(UBound(data))
    buffer = data
    For i = 0 To (UBound(data) - 1)
        Put #fileNo, i + 1, CByte(buffer(i))
    Next i

    Close #fileNo

'    Shell ("explorer.exe " & path)

End Function


Function ReadFromFile(path)

    Application.StatusBar = "Reading " & path

    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Dim fileInt As Integer: fileInt = FreeFile
    Open path For Binary Access Read As #fileInt
    ReDim bytes(0 To LOF(fileInt) - 1)
    Get #fileInt, , bytes
    Close #fileInt

    ReadFromFile = bytes

End Function

Sub UpdatePython_Click()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim path As String: path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\python.exe.original"
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    bytes = ReadFromFile(path)

    Worksheets("PythonEXE").Columns(1).EntireColumn.Clear

    Dim cell As range
    Set cell = Worksheets("PythonEXE").range("A1")

    For Each chunk In bytes
        cell.Value = chunk
        Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next chunk

    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub


Sub WriteCompiler_Click()

    Dim TotalRows As Long
    Dim bytes() As Byte

    TotalRows = Worksheets("PythonEXE").Rows(Worksheets("PythonEXE").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim bytes(TotalRows)

    For i = 0 To TotalRows
        bytes(i) = CByte(Worksheets("PythonEXE").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value)
    Next i

    Dim path As String: path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\python.exe.written"
    If Dir(path) <> "" Then
        Kill path
    End If
    WriteToFile path, bytes

    Shell ActiveWorkbook.path & "\checksum.bat", vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```